# Why are two identical namespaces here~~~~~ in the prestashop folder

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

[the picture in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvUee.png)

There are two identical namespaces here ~~~~

I can't find the second prestashop folder in the first prestashop folder!!

Answer (score 2):

The Prestashop namespaces do not follow the folder structure.
The SessionHandlerInterface is located at src/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php and has the namespace

> PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Session

```
namespace PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Session;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\PhpBridgeSessionStorage;

class SessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{ ... }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer~  So what structure does it follow.......   what ' s  way~~~